# permalink for group type

Tags: buddypress

I have crated two group types. For example football and hockey.
IS it possible to have a permalink for these group types so I would see all groups under this group types at the frontend?
I used the buddypress plugin for creating the groups and the group types.

Comment: which plugin do you use to create these groups ?

Comment: Yes, but can you share your code or mention what content type you created? Archives will vary depending on whether you created a custom post type, taxonomy, or something else entirely.

Comment: I used buddypress for creating the groups and group types